# CSS3 Animate It changes position and width properties for some elements on mobile devices

Tags: jquery, css, mobile, responsive-design

I have this weird problem with some of my blog post pages, eg. http://www.stgobsas.dk/blog/buenosaires/index.html

The problem seems to be with my CSS3 Animate It plugin. It seems to work great when viewing in a desktop browser of any width (I have tested down to 400 px). But when I view it on a mobile device (and also through Chrome's developer tools using the device mode) it changes the position property of my `<header>` and .header-image from fixed to something "not fixed" and it makes my header/menu bar take up more horizontal space, eg. 760 px where the .main-wrapper takes up 375 px like it should (this is for iPhone 6). I really don't understand why this problem only occurs on mobile browsers, and not on a desktop browser even though the window width is the same.

Have a look at the bottom of my script.js file. The second last code block is for my blog pages and it causes the problem. The last code block is for my front page and it causes a similar problem, however the width of the header/menu bar shrinks while the animation goes on and then ends up being fine again.

Update: if you look on it through the device mode in Chrome with the size of an iPad (or anything bigger than 700 px) you can see the same problem, but when you scroll all the way down to the bottom, where the last animations are waiting for the user to scroll into view, then the problem disappears after those animations are over. Then everything is good again. So it must be a problem with the CSS3 Animate It plugin. But why does this happen?

I hope someone can figure out what is going wrong!

Comment: Share your code on jsfiddle

Comment: Hi Madan. I could do that, but it would take me quite some time to re-build the example. Is it not possible for you to inspect my code through the developer tools in your preferred browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after first analysis, it seems that it's caused by :

```
<img src="buenosairescover.jpg" class="fullsize" height="1200" witdh="1600">
```

Remove `width="1600"` and `height="1200"`

And the content of the div with the class "details-container".

If you remove that div and the width of the image, the problem dissapears.
That's a first interesting track !

Comment: I found that it was due to the class `.bounceInRight` from the small images in details. If you remove the properties: `transform: translateX(400px)` and `-webkit-transform: translateX(400px)`, it removes the problem

Comment: I tried your first answer and that didn't change anything for me.

Your second answer sounds better, but if I remove those I can't any longer use the animation. Maybe I just have to choose another kind of animation.

But can you explain me why there is this difference on mobile browsers and laptop/desktop browsers?

Comment: I actually don't know why there are different behaviors on mobile browsers since I never used animate.css. However, you can resolve the problem by adding a `overflow:hidden;` in the container of the image, so it doesn't extend it. The container here is divs with class `details`

Comment: Ok. But thank you so much! It made my day! I should have asked yesterday instead of wasting precious time :-)

Comment: No problem ! Don't forget to put a tick so people will know your problem has been solved !